# Why getting compilation error while calling overloaded method and deciding argument type using if-else as parameter

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overloading

I am trying to call the overloaded method using if-else statement to decide which type of argument to pass so that appropriate method can be invoked. I am getting compilation error.
any idea why I am getting compilation error ? If call method separately using if-else check outside , it works fine.

```
public class A {
}

public class B {
}

public class RuleCheck {

    public void check(A a) {

    }

    public void check(B b) {

    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        testRule(a);
        testRule(b);
    }

    private static void testRule(Object o) {

        RuleCheck ruleCheck = new RuleCheck();
        ruleCheck.check(o instanceof A ? (A) o : (B) o);//Compilation problem here : Cannot resolve method 'check(java.lang.Object)'


       //Following code works fine
       if (o instanceof A)
           ruleCheck.check((A) o);
       else if (o instanceof B)
           ruleCheck.check((B) o);
       }
```

}

Comment: what type should the result of the expression ` ... ? (A) o : (B) o` be? (Java is strongly typed {not sure if that is the correct term}; the types must be solved at compilation time) - details [JLS 15.25.3. Reference Conditional Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3)

Comment: Yes. This makes sense. Compiler will get confused which to call during compile time. Hence its giving completion problem.